# Error Load Fixtures

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

When I use :

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=/var/www/Symfony/src/BISSAP/ForumBundle/DataFixtures/ORM
```

I get :

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                                                       
  An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Post (content, date_creation, date_modif, slug, topic_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?  
  , ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["Contenu du post!! gGasp Strategie duplication article no commentSyndrome 60", "2015-08-21 14:55:24",   
  "2015-08-21 14:55:24", "slug-slug", null, 34]:                                                                                      
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'topic_id' cannot be null

[PDOException]                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'topic_id' cannot be null
```

**Entity Post.php :**

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="topic", inversedBy="Posts", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $topic;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="Posts", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_creation", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateCreation;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_modif", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateModif;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $slug;


/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
$this->dateCreation = new \DateTime();
$this->dateModif = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return Post
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set dateCreation
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
 * @return Post
 */
public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
{
    $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateCreation
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateCreation()
{
    return $this->dateCreation;
}

/**
 * Set dateModif
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateModif
 * @return Post
 */
public function setDateModif($dateModif)
{
    $this->dateModif = $dateModif;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateModif
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateModif()
{
    return $this->dateModif;
}

/**
 * Set slug
 *
 * @param string $slug
 * @return Post
 */
public function setSlug($slug)
{
    $this->slug = $slug;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get slug
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSlug()
{
    return $this->slug;
}

/**
 * Set Topic
 *
 * @param \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic $topic
 * @return Post
 */
public function setTopic(\BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic $topic)
{
    $this->Topic = $topic;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Topic
 *
 * @return \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic 
 */
public function getTopic()
{
    return $this->Topic;
}

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User $user
 * @return Post
 */
public function setUser(\BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
}
```

---

**Entity Topic.php :**

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/*use BISSAP\BodyConcept\Entity\Forum;
*/

/**
 * Topic
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\TopicRepository")
 */
class Topic
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Forum", inversedBy="Topics", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $forum;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $Posts
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="Topic", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
 */
private $posts;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="Topics", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="view_count", type="integer")
 */
private $viewCount;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_creation", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateCreation;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="reply_count", type="integer")
 */
private $replyCount;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $slug;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="genre", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $genre;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_post", type="integer")
 */
private $lastPost;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
 */
private $content;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param integer $user
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * Set viewCount
 *
 * @param integer $viewCount
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setViewCount($viewCount)
{
    $this->viewCount = $viewCount;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get viewCount
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getViewCount()
{
    return $this->viewCount;
}

/**
 * Set dateCreation
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
{
    $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateCreation
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateCreation()
{
    return $this->dateCreation;
}

/**
 * Set replyCount
 *
 * @param integer $replyCount
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setReplyCount($replyCount)
{
    $this->replyCount = $replyCount;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get replyCount
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getReplyCount()
{
    return $this->replyCount;
}

/**
 * Set slug
 *
 * @param string $slug
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setSlug($slug)
{
    $this->slug = $slug;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get slug
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSlug()
{
    return $this->slug;
}

/**
 * Set genre
 *
 * @param string $genre
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setGenre($genre)
{
    $this->genre = $genre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get genre
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getGenre()
{
    return $this->genre;
}

/**
 * Set lastPost
 *
 * @param integer $lastPost
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setLastPost($lastPost)
{
    $this->lastPost = $lastPost;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lastPost
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getLastPost()
{
    return $this->lastPost;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set forum
 *
 * @param Forum $forum
 * @return Topic
 */
/*public function setForum(\BISSAP\BodyConceptBundle\Entity\Forum $forum)*/
public function setForum(Forum $forum)
{
    $this->forum = $forum;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get forum
 *
 * @return \BISSAP\BodyConceptBundle\Entity\Forum 
 */
public function getForum()
{
    return $this->forum;
}
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->posts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
$this->dateCreation = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * Add posts
 *
 * @param \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post $posts
 * @return Topic
 */
public function addPost(\BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
{
    $this->posts[] = $posts;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove posts
 *
 * @param \BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post $posts
 */
public function removePost(\BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
{
    $this->posts->removeElement($posts);
}

/**
 * Get posts
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->posts;
}
}
```

---

**Fixtures : **
  **LaodPost.php :**

```
namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Post;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;

class LoadPost extends AbstractFixture implements FixtureInterface,  OrderedFixtureInterface
{

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{

  $data = array(
    array($this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User-0'),'Contenu du post!! gGasp Strategie duplication article no commentSyndrome 60','slug-slug',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic-0')),
    array($this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User-0'),'Contenu du post!! gGasp Strategie duplication article no commentSyndrome 60','slug-slug',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic-1')));

  foreach ($data as $P) {
    $post = new Post();
    $post->setUser($P[0]);
    $post->setContent($P[1]);
    $post->setSlug($P[2]);
    $post->setTopic($P[3]);

    $manager->persist($post);
    }  
/*TEST OK*/
    $myFile = fopen('/home/sebastien/test_topic.txt','a+');
            fputs($myFile, $this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic-0')->getUser()->getPseudo());
    fclose($myFile);
/*END TEST*/

  $manager->flush();
}

public function getOrder()
{
return 5;
}
}
```

**LoadTopic.php:**

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Forum;
use BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Category;
use BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;

class LoadTopic extends AbstractFixture implements FixtureInterface,    OrderedFixtureInterface
{

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{

  $data = array(
    array('Perte de Volume Musculaire Inexpliqué',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User-0'),'60','25','slug-slug','genre','256','Besoins d\'aide pitié...',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Forum-0')),
    array('Perte de Volume Mental Inexpliqué',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User-1'),'60','25','slug-slug','genre','256','Besoins d\'aide pitié...',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Forum-0')),
    array('Perte de Volume Cosmik Inexpliqué',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User-1'),'60','25','slug-slug','genre','256','Besoins d\'aide pitié...',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Forum-0')),

    array('Perte de Volume Sonor Inexpliqué',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User-2'),'60','25','slug-slug','genre','256','Besoins d\'aide pitié...',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Forum-0')),
    array('Perte de Volume Sonor Inexpliqué',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User-2'),'60','25','slug-slug','genre','256','Besoins d\'aide pitié...',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Forum-0')),
    array('Perte de Volume Sonor Inexpliqué',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User-2'),'60','25','slug-slug','genre','256','Besoins d\'aide pitié...',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Forum-0')),
    array('Perte de Volume Strategique Inexpliqué',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\User-0'),'60','25','slug-slug','genre','256','Besoins d\'aide pitié...',$this->getReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Forum-0')));

$i=0;
    foreach ($data as $Top) {
    $topic = new Topic();
    $topic->setTitle($Top[0]);
    $topic->setUser($Top[1]);
    $topic->setViewCount($Top[2]);
    $topic->setReplyCount($Top[3]);
    $topic->setSlug($Top[4]);
    $topic->setGenre($Top[5]);
    $topic->setLastPost($Top[6]);
    $topic->setContent($Top[7]);
$topic->setForum($Top[8]);
$this->addReference('BISSAP\ForumBundle\Entity\Topic-'.$i,$topic);
$i++;

    $manager->persist($topic);

    }  

  $manager->flush();
}

public function getOrder()
{
return 4;
}
}
```

***I load, LoadTopic.php in first and then LoadPost.php***

In all, i have 5 fixtures (LoadCategory.php, LoadForum.php, LoadPost.php, LoadTopic.php, LoadUser.php)
Thank U.

Comment: Try to change a low register in `targetEntity="topic"` to `targetEntity="Topic"`  on your $topic annotation. Just in case.

Comment: Hi! @basilup, give more detail please...!

Comment: In annotation to the $topic field in Post entity you have this: `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="topic", inversedBy="Posts", cascade={"persist"})` ->  in `targetEntity="topic"` try to replace the reference to Topic entity to `targetEntity="Topic"` (`Topic` with the first letter in uppercase)

Comment: I changed this, after I use ( php app/console doctrine:generate:entities BISSAP/ForumBundle/Entity/Post) i don't if this action update the Entity. And after, i try fixture load but i get same error;

Comment: OK, seems a letter case is irrelevant ...

Comment: I've tryed minimal working example with Post and Topic on my machine - [gist](https://gist.github.com/basilup/039dc1fd6728140edae6) - and it works fine, no errors. May be the error that  you have provided occures in some another place in your code?

Comment: Have you try also Wih my fixtures?

Comment: No, because I thought that the cause of the error is not in the fixtures. Or you have the error only during loading fixtures? Have you tried persist Post and Topic for example from some of your controllers?

Comment: I'will tried, monday..! I can't moved my code for this weekend end. Good weekend.

Comment: OK, good luck and good weekend!

Comment: Now, it's ok. I changed `$this->Topic = $topic;` to `$this->topic = $topic;` in Post.php

Comment: Oh really there was an error, I haven't noticed it last time =)